# C++ map value passing

Tags: c++

This is my code for program trying to search or display whole map which containing fruit quantity.

For some reason the search is not functioning(didn't return any results) and the code suppose to display all quantity is only returning the last entry of the map.

The following is some fragment of the code.

Please ignore if there are more packages included or syntax error as I am not copying the whole code to here.

Edited with typo corrections and added the fruit.h

The fruit.txt

```
apple
02
orange
06
pear
03
lemon
07
```

It is read from main.cpp and prompt input for task selection.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include "fruit.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void readFile(); //read file    
    readFile();

    void perform(int); //case selection
    int caseInput;

    cout << "Press 1 for search" << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to show all" << endl;
    cout << "choice: ";

    cin >> caseInput;
    perform(caseInput);
}

void readFile() //read line and pass to fruit.cpp using vector
{
    vector<fruit> fruitVector;
    string fruitName;
    int quantity;
    ifstream file;
    txt.open("fruit.txt");
    while (!txt.eof())
    {
        getline(txt, fruitName);
        getline(txt, quantity);
        fruitVector.push_back(fruit(fruitName, quantity));
    }
    txt.close();
}

void perform(int caseInput)
{
    string searchTerm;
    switch (caseInput)
    {
        case 1: // search function
        {
            cout << "input: ";
            cin >> searchTerm;
            taskOne(searchTerm);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            tasktwo(); // not done yet, but nvm
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my fruit.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include "fruit.h"

using namespace std;

fruit::fruit(string fruitName, int quantity)
{
    fruitMap[fruitName] = quantity; //storing vectors to map
    passMap(fruitMap); //pass the map to task.cpp
};
```

This is my task.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<string, int> fruitMap;

void passMap(map<string, int>input)
{
    fruitMap = input;
}
void taskOne(string searchTerm)
{
    auto it = fruitMap.find(searchTerm);
    if(it != fruitMap.end())
    {
        cout << "output = " << endl;
        cout << it->second << endl; // should print out the quantity of fruit
    }
    //in fact i try output the whole map using the code:
    //
    //for (auto it = fruitMap.begin(); it != fruitMap.end(); ++it)
    //{
    //    cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";
    //}
    //
    //but it only output the last line which is:
    //lemon 07
}
```

The fruit.h

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "task.h"

class fruit{
private:
    std::string fruitName;
    std::int quantity;
    std::map<std::string, int> fruitMap;
public:
    fruit(std:string, int);
}
```

Comment: can you show the content of fruit.h?

Comment: In `main`, the local `caseInput` is set to the user input from the command line.  But `caseNum` is passed to the `perform` function.  Is there a typo somewhere?  In `readFile`, the local `fruitVector` instance is gone when `readFile` is completed.  Is this what you want?  Since you already have a `map` container inside the `fruit` class and then call `passMap` for each fruit instance, why not declare a map instance that is local to the `main` function instead?  Please draw some pictures on paper for how all of these containers interrelate.  You will find better ways to implement the system.

Comment: sorry for the silly typo. Yes the vector is working as I want, which is looping and pass values to fruit.cpp. I did try to do the output in the fruit.cpp and is was working fine, only meet the error when trying to pass and display the map in task.cpp

Comment: you are constructing one map in each fruit object, and that map only contains the one entry, which is the name/quantity you constructed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every fruit has its own map where it stores itself. you need one map common to all fruits. you can achieve this by making fruitMap static, or, even better completely seperate the map from the fruit and pass a reference to the functions